# How to create var names in Javascript from JSON property

Tags: javascript, json, variables

I need to set simple var in Javascript, named after JSON properties from a loop on each JSON rows. Their values would also come from JSON.

For example, here is my template:`var paris = {lat: 48.866667, lng: 2.333333};`

But with a loop on the Json rows
var **json[i].code** = {lat: **json[i].latitude**, lng: **json[i].longitude**};

Here is my JS code, so far I couldn't figure out how to make it work ... Thanks for your precious help.

```
function initMap() {

  //my template 
    var paris = {lat: 48.866667, lng: 2.333333};

    //my actual data
    var json=[{"code":"london","latitude":"50.633333","longitude":"3.066667"},{"code":"berlin","latitude":"47.478419","longitude":"-0.563166"}];            

    //my code to create my vars from Json
    for( var i=0;i< json.length; i++ ){
        var json[i].code = "{lat:" + json[i].latitude + " , lng: " +json[i].longitude +" }";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: To confirm, you want a dynamic var name based on your json property?

Comment: You might consider converting your json to an object first, and then use the object in your for loop - take a look at JSON.Parse().
Or instead of defining something that looks like json in your array, change it to an object by removing the "" around the identifiers ("code" becomes code etc.)

Comment: To begin with, your `var json=...` is _not_ JSON, it is a Javascript array of objects. JSON stands for JavaScript Object Notation, and is a way to represent Javascript objects (including arrays) as text, and that text needs to be parsed to turn it back into Javascript objects. Next, you don't want to (can't) create vars named for the _city codes_ — there would be no way to refer to them in the source you write, you _must_ use some kind of map with the city names (the 'code') as the key. e.g. `var cities={};` `cities['london'] = { "code":"london", "latitude":50.63, "longitude":3.06 };`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a conversion using `Array.reduce` which works back to IE10:

```js
function initMap() {
  //Your template 
  var paris = {lat: 48.866667, lng: 2.333333};

  //Your actual data
  var json =[
    {"code":"london","latitude":"50.633333","longitude":"3.066667"},
    {"code":"berlin","latitude":"47.478419","longitude":"-0.563166"}
  ]; 

  //Code to create new Object
  var newObj = json.reduce((obj, data) => {
    obj[data.code] = {lat:data.latitude, lng: data.longitude};
    return obj;
  }, {});
  
  console.log(JSON.stringify(newObj,0,2));
}

initMap();
```

This converts each entry into an entry in a new object using the value for `code` as the key and the new data is a object that matches your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

First, when a variable is declared, you should not use the keyword `var` before like this: `var json[i].code`, juste write: `json[i].code`.

Then, when you use JSON inside your code, you don't need to put anything between two `""` in Javascript.

Just do this:

```
{
  latitude: 50.6,
  longitude: 50.7
}
```

And not this:

```
"{
  latitude: 50.6,
  longitude: 50.7
}"
```

Then, you have the result :

```js
function initMap() {
    var paris = {
        lat: 48.866667,
        lng: 2.333333
    };

    var json = [
        {
            code: "london",
            latitude: 50.633333,
            longitude: 3.066667
        },
        {
            code: "berlin",
            latitude: 47.478419,
            longitude: -0.563166
        }
    ];            

    //my code to create my vars from Json
    for(var i = 0; i < json.length; i++){
        json[i] = {
            code: json[i].code,
            lat: json[i].latitude,
            lng: json[i].longitude
        };
    }
    
    console.log(json);
}

initMap();
```

Comment: He will lose the property names here which I imagine is important. How will we know which element is for london? Which is for berlin? This code doesn't account for that.

Comment: Yep, that's a mistake sorry

Comment: I didn't understood if he wanted to create a JSON object with the name of the city, or if he wanted this name to be IN the main JSON object

Answer (score -1):

If I understand correctly, you are trying to create an individual variable for each row.

You can do this with either global variables by using the window property or if you want it locally scoped to the function you can instead create a local parent object.

```js
//Defining the variables globally
function initMapGlobal() {

    //my template 
    var paris = {
        lat: 48.866667,
        lng: 2.333333
    };

    //my actual data
    var json = [{
        "code": "london",
        "latitude": "50.633333",
        "longitude": "3.066667"
    }, {
        "code": "berlin",
        "latitude": "47.478419",
        "longitude": "-0.563166"
    }];

    //my code to create my vars from Json
    for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
        window[json[i].code] = JSON.parse('{"lat":' + json[i].latitude + ' , "lng": ' + json[i].longitude + ' }');
    }
}

initMapGlobal();
console.log('Outside of Function - Global');
console.log('Variable Value: ', london);
console.log('Value of London Latitude: ', london.lat);
console.log('\n**************\n');


//Defining the variables local to the function
function initMapLocal() {
    var cityParent = {};

    //my template 
    var paris = {
        lat: 48.866667,
        lng: 2.333333
    };

    //my actual data
    var json = [{
        "code": "london",
        "latitude": "50.633333",
        "longitude": "3.066667"
    }, {
        "code": "berlin",
        "latitude": "47.478419",
        "longitude": "-0.563166"
    }];

    //my code to create my vars from Json
    for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
        cityParent[json[i].code] = JSON.parse('{"lat":' + json[i].latitude + ' , "lng": ' + json[i].longitude + ' }');
    }

    console.log('Inside of function:');
    console.log('Variable Value: ', cityParent.london);
    console.log('Value of London Latitude: ', cityParent.london.lat);
    console.log('\n**************\n');
}


initMapLocal();
console.log('Outside of function: (these will crash because they are local)');
console.log('Variable Value: ', cityParent.london);
console.log('Value of London Latitude: ', cityParent.london.lat);
```

Answer (score -2):

```
function initMap() {

  //my template 
    var paris = {lat: 48.866667, lng: 2.333333};

    //my actual data
    var json=[{"code":"london","latitude":"50.633333","longitude":"3.066667"},{"code":"berlin","latitude":"47.478419","longitude":"-0.563166"}];            

    //my code to create my vars from Json
    for( var i=0;i< json.length; i++ ){
        var obj = {};
        obj.lat = json[i].latitude;
        obj.lng = json[i].longitude;
        window[json[i].code] = obj;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your parse is going to be invalid.

Comment: Hopefully, fixed now. Hard to debug on phone.

Comment: Still have several errors in your answer. 1. you left an invalid } 2. Your json parse is still malformed because you can't json.parse with a single quote. 3. Your end json (even after fixing the malformed) will return invalid response. 

[
  {
    "code": {
      "lat": 50.633333,
      "lng": 3.066667
    },
    "latitude": "50.633333",
    "longitude": "3.066667"
  },
  {
    "code": {
      "lat": 47.478419,
      "lng": -0.563166
    },
    "latitude": "47.478419",
    "longitude": "-0.563166"
  }
]